# p5js positioning canvas Uncaught Type Error

Tags: javascript, canvas, p5.js

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in this problem. I'm using OpenProcessing and trying to put a canvas element within a container but I'm running into an Uncaught TypeError, Cannot read property "id"

I'm copying the same code from https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Positioning-your-canvas

```
function setup() {
    var cnv = createCanvas(100, 100);
    var x = (windowWidth - width) / 2;
    var y = (windowHeight - height) / 2;
    cnv.position(x, y);
    background(255, 0, 200);
}
```

This is my code...

```
function setup() {
    var cnv = createCanvas(500, 100);
    cnv.id("hello");
    cnv.position(0,0);
} 

function draw() {
}
```

Here is a link to my sketch...
https://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/407956

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has something to do with OpenProcessing because your code works absolutely fine on [p5 editor](https://alpha.editor.p5js.org/) (and locally).
The `createCanvas` method returns an object so calling the `id` function on it should not return *"Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"* as it did on OpenProcessing so `createCanvas` possibly isn't returning anything, and it should return an object according to [p5 documentation.](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createCanvas).

You can try positioning the canvas using css as described in [p5 wiki](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Positioning-your-canvas) by adding a stylesheet that uses [flexible box layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) or try not using OpenProcessing if possible.

Comment: Thank you for your quick and timely response. I ended up adjusting the z-index values of my other elements to compensate for the lack of control over the canvas z-index. My entire project is built with open processing and it would take much longer to migrate to P5 editor. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: My intent was not to indicate to migrate to p5 web editor, it's very basic and is just for beginners who want to try out p5. It doesn't provide much functionality. But, for your future projects, you might want to consider [Codepen](http://codepen.io/).

Answer (score 0):

The `createCanvas()` function is not returning anything. This doesn't jive with what's in [the P5.js reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createCanvas), so I understand your confusion.

My guess is that OpenProcessing uses a slightly modified version of P5.js, because it doesn't really require any positioning. The canvas is always centered in the screen.

If you're going to continue using OpenProcessing, then I'd stop worrying about positioning the canvas yourself. Or I'd search for existing sketches that reposition the canvas and see how they do it.

Even if the `createCanvas()` function returns soemthing, I'm not sure what the `id()` function is supposed to do in this case. Nothing in the link you posted uses that function. Nonetheless, it seems to work fine if I run it locally.